# Hibernate Criteria - get sum(hours between two dates)

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the following table:

```
     start_date      |      end_date       |       age
---------------------+---------------------+-----------------
 2020-11-30 09:00:00 | 2020-12-05 23:00:00 | 5 days 14:00:00
 2020-11-30 09:00:00 | 2020-11-30 10:00:00 | 01:00:00
 2020-11-30 09:00:00 | 2020-12-03 19:00:00 | 3 days 10:00:00
 2020-11-30 09:00:00 | 2020-12-03 19:00:00 | 3 days 10:00:00
 2020-11-30 09:00:00 | 2020-12-03 19:00:00 | 3 days 10:00:00
 2020-12-01 09:00:00 | 2020-12-03 19:00:00 | 2 days 10:00:00
 2020-12-03 09:00:00 | 2020-12-03 19:00:00 | 10:00:00
 2020-12-04 09:00:00 | 2020-12-04 19:00:00 | 10:00:00
```

from the following query:

```
select start_date, end_date, age(end_date, start_date) from event;
```

how can I get the sum(number of hours/day) between start and end date for each day in java Hibernate Criteria?

until now:

```
    public List<StatsDto> lastXDaysEvents(LocalDateTime xDaysBefore, LocalDateTime xDaysAfter) {
        Session session = openSession();

        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Event.class);
        
        cr.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        cr.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate", xDaysBefore)); 
        cr.add(Restrictions.lt("endDate", xDaysAfter));
//      cr.createAlias("date_part('hour', age(end_date, start_date))", "sumDate");
//      cr.add(Expression.sql("datediff('Hour', start_date, end_date)"));
        
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList(); 
        projectionList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(start_date) as sDate", "sDate", new String[] { "sDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }), "x"));
        projectionList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.rowCount(), "y"));
//    projectionList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("sum(sumDate)"), "y"));
        
        cr.addOrder(Order.asc("x"));
        cr.setProjection(projectionList);
        cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StatsDto.class));
                
        List<StatsDto> result = cr.list();

        return result;
    }
```

I get the rowCount() 'y' projection which gives the number of events grouped by date but not all events have exactly one hour. How can I get in the 'y' projection the sum(hour_diff(start_date, end_date))?

I think I need to:

- create an aliast for "date_part('hour', age(end_date, start_date))"
- create a sum projection for it

but I don't know how.

Comment: What are the data types for `start_date` and `end_date` fields? Also `age()` will not properly catch DST transitions. Example in `PST/PDT`:  `select '11/1/2020 10:00'::timestamptz -  '10/31/2020 22:00'::timestamptz;  13:00:00` vs `select age('11/1/2020 10:00'::timestamptz,'10/31/2020 22:00'::timestamptz); 12:00:00`

Comment: FYI, `date_part('hour', age(end_date, start_date))` is not going to do what you think it will: `select date_part('hour', age('11/1/2020 10:00'::timestamptz,'10/31/2020 22:00'::timestamptz)); 12`. It just returns the hour portion of a timestamp or interval.

Comment: 'FYI ...' yes ... this is the first question, I tried with date_part ... :) DST can be ommited, thanks

Comment: I don't understand any of your previous comment. You will need to be more specific and detailed. Also include that information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The AGE function returns the time between 2 timestamps as an INTERVAL. The DATE_PART function extracts a specific portion of a timestamp or interval. See documentation [9.9. Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html). If you want the total duration in terms of specific units (in this case hours) then you must apply the part conversions to calculate the value.

```
with test_dates (start_date,end_date) as 
     (values ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-05 23:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-11-30 10:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-01 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-03 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-04 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-04 19:00:00'::timestamp) 
     ) 
select start_date
     , end_date
     , 24*date_part('day',diff)+date_part('hour',diff)  num_hours
  from ( select start_date,end_date,age(end_date,start_date) diff
           from test_dates
       ) d
```

You actually do not need the AGE function as direct subtraction of timestamps produces the same interval. So (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4780511e17274ea2e1171e41705f932f) for both)

```
with test_dates (start_date,end_date) as 
     (values ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-05 23:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-11-30 10:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-01 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-03 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-04 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-04 19:00:00'::timestamp) 
     ) 
select start_date
     , end_date
     , 24*date_part('day',end_date-start_date) + date_part('hours', end_date-start_date) num_hours
  from work_dates;
```

Finally to get daily total hours just sum the result:

```
 with test_dates (start_date,end_date) as 
     (values ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-05 23:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-11-30 10:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-11-30 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-01 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-03 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-03 19:00:00'::timestamp)  
           , ('2020-12-04 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-12-04 19:00:00'::timestamp) 
     ) 
select start_date::date for_date
     , sum( (24*date_part('day',diff)+date_part('hour',diff)))  daily_num_hours
  from ( select start_date,end_date,age(end_date,start_date) diff
           from test_dates
       ) d
group by start_date::date
order by start_date::date;
```